# WM_CLOSE doesn't work and the application is not resizable

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

1. When I attempt to close the dialog, I expect the application to close, but it doesn't. I assume something is wrong with `WM_CLOSE`.
2. The application is not resizable. How do I make it so?
3. Do I really need `UpdateWindow(hWnd)`?

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

#include "resource.h"

#pragma comment(linker, "\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return TRUE;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return FALSE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
            EndDialog(hwnd, IDOK);
            break;
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hwnd, IDCANCEL);
            break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
    
    return TRUE;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    
    HWND hWnd = CreateDialogParamW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDD_MAIN), nullptr, &DialogProc, 0);
    
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Dialog Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Resource.rc

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "winres.h"
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""winres.h""\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_MAIN, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 302
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 169
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_MAIN DIALOGEX 0, 0, 309, 176
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Test"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST2,48,30,235,56,LBS_SORT | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    GROUPBOX        "Static",IDC_STATIC,146,92,48,40
    PUSHBUTTON      "Button1",IDC_BUTTON1,215,127,50,14
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
//

IDD_MAIN AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0
END

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

resource.h

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by Resource.rc
//
#define IDD_MAIN                        103
#define IDC_LIST2                       1005
#define IDC_BUTTON1                     1006

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        105
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1007
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: `EndDialog` have no effect for dialog created with `CreateDialogParamW` (internally it only post `WM_NULL`). `WM_CLOSE` you must got if press on close button or atl+f4. and you select `DS_MODALFRAME` - it not resizable

Comment: @RbMm, thank you! `DS_FIXEDSYS` fixed the resizing. What about the closing? What should I use in order to fix it?

Comment: Looks like you aren't calling the default WndProc for the `WM_DESTROY` message. Your `default` case returns `FALSE` for `WM_DESTROY`, which is telling the system you've handled the message.

Comment: @AdrianMole - in `DialogProc` never need call default WndProc

Comment: @nop - *What about the closing?* instead `EndDialog` call `DestroyWindow`, case WM_CLOSE you can remove at all. `PostQuitMessage(0);` call from `WM_NCDESTROY`

Comment: @RbMm Sorry - that's correct. But returning `FALSE` (as default) for `WM_DESTROY` will prevent the system from handling that message properly ... I think.

Comment: @AdrianMole - no, *If the dialog box procedure returns FALSE, the dialog manager performs the default dialog operation in response to the message.* . so ok return false on `WM_DESTROY` or `WM_NCDESTROY`

Comment: @RbMm OK. So, there's still a conflict, because the `WM_CLOSE` message in OP's code also returns `FALSE`, so what will the default dialog operation (attempt to) do, in that case?

Comment: @AdrianMole - no conflict. in current code dialog must be closed on press close or alt+f4. also need change `GetMessageW(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0)` to `GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: When I tried running OP's code, clicking the close button does close the window but the application stays running (invisibly).

Comment: @AdrianMole, yes, exactly

Comment: **1** `GetMessageW(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0)` -> `GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0)` **2** remove `case WM_CLOSE:` **3** `EndDialog(hwnd, );` -> `DestroyWindow(hwnd);` **4** add `case WM_NCDESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0);`

Comment: @RbMm, just like that: https://pastebin.com/0gYEaAFg? Also you could paste it as an answer. Because it seems to be working! I just don't know what else I should remove.

Comment: @nop no, code absolute wrong. no sense call `DestroyWindow(hwnd);` on `WM_NCDESTROY` where handle `WM_COMMAND` ?

Comment: @RbMm, I removed it. I don't understand where I should add DestroyWindow tho. Can you type it as an answer, entirely?

Comment: @nop - i already say this **3** EndDialog(hwnd, ); -> DestroyWindow(hwnd);

Comment: @RbMm,https://pastebin.com/SAhrCFvJ?

Comment: yes, this look like correct

Comment: @RbMm, like everything? What about the returns in DialogProc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are passing `hWnd` as a parameter to `GetMessage()`. This causes `GetMessage()` to only retrieve messages for the window. But `WM_QUIT` is not sent to your window, but to your thread. Since `GetMessage()` never retrieves the `WM_QUIT` message, the message loop never exits.

The proper approach is to pass `nullptr` instead of `hWnd`.

Comment: yes, but yet one point here - `while (GetMessageW(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0))` wrong result check. must be `while (0 < GetMessageW(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0))` because api return `-1` on error. if use second form - it also break loop - because -1 returned after `DestroyWindow` call and `hWnd` not valid more

Comment: See [The dangers of filtering window messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493) and [When will GetMessage return -1?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873)